# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges solution oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, plsql

```
Create or replace procedure myprocedure
is 
   stmt varchar2(1000);
   stmt2 varchar2(1000);
begin
    stmt := 'create global temporary table temp(id number(10))';
    execute immediate stmt;
    stmt2 := 'insert into temp(id) values (10)';
    execute immediate stmt2;
end;
```

when i execute the procedure

```
exec myprocedure;
```

i got the error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "I3.MYPROCEDURE", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Did the user you are using received the privileges to create tables through a role? Those are not active inside PL/SQL. The user needs to be granted the privilege directly.

Comment: What is line 7  at "I3.MYPROCEDURE"? Which statement does cause the error? Is this 'execute immediate stmt;'? What is line 2?

Comment: line 7 is execute immediate stmt @miracle173

Comment: so the 'create global temporary table temp(id number(10))' raises the error. Which privilgese are necessary to create a temporary table?

Comment: Read first comment.Are you able to create table  from sql*plus?